# Magento 2 set custom variable to use in email template on all emails

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email, email-templates

**I want to be able to add a custom variable through an event observer of some sort which enables me to output this variable in any given email template.**

I know I can make an event observer for example on `email_order_set_template_vars_before`, but then it would only be outputted on order emails. Is there a global event in which this is possible?

> So far I've seen it is only possible on a few events. Or is there
>   another way without events to get this done? I want the variable to be
>   accessible in the header or footer email template.

Comment: Did you try using plugin?

Comment: @SohelRana No i have not, i am not familiar with plugins. Is this a viable way of achieving my goal?

Comment: @ElFietsbel are you able to find this solution ? i am also looking this type of functionality.